# Show elements contains word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 articles. One article has category - news, but second article has category - design. I want to show article that has category news, but other articles will hide. How to do it?

```html
      <div class="article">
    <div class="title_article">
 <h2>News about you</h2>
 <div class="description">
     <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex mollitia dolores dignissimos velit voluptas.
      Hic perspiciatis dolorum ullam delectus voluptatibus atque nobis aspernatur! Consequatur quo eos delectus! 
   Laboriosam, reprehenderit vel. </p>
     <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: News </p>
        </div>
    </div>
   <a href="news/article.php">
   <div class="article">
       <div class="title_article">
           <h2>Design about you</h2></a>
               <div class="description">
            <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex mollitia dolores dignissimos velit voluptas.
      Hic perspiciatis dolorum ullam delectus voluptatibus atque nobis aspernatur! Consequatur quo eos delectus! 
   Laboriosam, reprehenderit vel. </p>
     <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: Design </p>
               </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: Well, firstly, make an effort. SO is a place to get coding help; we don't do the task for you.

Comment: data-attributes would make this so much easier

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS.

```
// style.css

.hide {
  display:none;
}

// index.html

<div class="hide"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a ton to go off of here but if you're looking for some jQuery functions something like this should work...

Also, your HTML was pretty badly unbalanced so I tried to fix it up to make more sense.

```js
function showByCategoryText(catText) {
  $('.article').hide()
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('p.category').html().indexOf(catText) !== -1;
    }).show();
}

function showNews() {
  showByCategoryText("News");
}

function showDesign() {
  showByCategoryText("Design");
}

showNews();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">


  <div class="title_article">
    <h2>News about you</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex mollitia dolores dignissimos velit voluptas. Hic perspiciatis dolorum ullam delectus voluptatibus atque nobis aspernatur! Consequatur quo eos delectus! Laboriosam, reprehenderit vel. </p>
    <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: News </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="article">


  <a href="news/article.php">
    <div class="title_article">
      <h2>Design about you</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="description">
    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex mollitia dolores dignissimos velit voluptas. Hic perspiciatis dolorum ullam delectus voluptatibus atque nobis aspernatur! Consequatur quo eos delectus! Laboriosam, reprehenderit vel. </p>
    <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: Design </p>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="showNews();">showNews</button>
<button onclick="showDesign();">showDesign</button>
```